# In LWC, How do I dynamically show the records of a listview if the listview is selected from a picklist

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, child-to-parent, lightninglistview, lwc-wire-getlistui

I obtained listviews using `getListUi` wire adapter. I populated these listviews into a picklist. What I'm trying to achieve is if I select a listview from the picklist, the records need to be updated dynamically. How do I achieve this.

Right now I tried doing this by making the picklist as child and table as parent and tried to communicate the `listViewApiName` to parent using @api. But the table doesn't show anything. No error also. What to do?

This is the code for obtaining `listViews`:

```
import { LightningElement,wire,track,api} from 'lwc';
import { getListUi} from 'lightning/uiListApi';
import PRODUCT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Product2';

export default class ShowListView extends LightningElement {
@track value;
@track allListViews;
@api progressValue;


@wire(getListUi, {objectApiName: PRODUCT_OBJECT})
wiredlistView({error,data}) {
    if(data){
        this.allListViews = data.lists;
        var listViewData = [];
    for(var i=0;i<this.allListViews.length;i++){
        listViewData.push({"label" : this.allListViews[i].label, "value" : this.allListViews[i].apiName});
    }
    this.allListViews = listViewData;
    }else if(error){
        console.log('An error has occurred:');
        console.log(error);
    }
}
handleChange(event) {
    this.value = event.detail.value;

    this.progressValue=event.target.value;
    const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent("progressvaluechange",{
        detail:this.progressValue
    });

    this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
}

}
```

This is the code for showing the records:

```
import { LightningElement,wire,api,track } from 'lwc';
import PRODUCT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Product2';   
import { getListUi} from 'lightning/uiListApi';

export default class ShowPicklistValues extends LightningElement {
@track sobjectResult;
@track progressValue = 'AllProducts';

@wire(getListUi, {objectApiName: PRODUCT_OBJECT,listViewApiName: {progressValue})
lastView({error,data}){
    
    if (data) {
        this.sobjectResult = data.records.records;  
    } else if (error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
}

handleValueChange(event) {
    this.progressValue = event.detail.value;
}
}
```

Once I replace the {progressValue} in the second code block(7th line) with `listViewApiName` like `'AllProducts'` it is working but is showing only for that particular listView. I need it to change dynamically.

Thank you and sorry for the long post. I'm new to SalesForce and don't know how to ask questions with minimal details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your question, you have a combo box populated with all list view names and that upon change in that you need to re-render your component with the records related to that list view.

In order for your wired service to fetch the new data, you will need to mark the property `progressValue` as dynamic and reactive. So your wired service declaration will look as below (not the `$`)

```
@wire(getListUi, {objectApiName: PRODUCT_OBJECT,listViewApiName: '$progressValue'})
lastView({error,data}) { 
    ... 
}
```

This will ensure that whenever a new list view value is selected in the combo box, the wired service is invoked with the latest value and the component is re-rendered accordingly.

Refer to the section *"Mark a Configuration Object Property as Dynamic and Reactive"* in [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/data_wire_service_about) to learn more about it. Excerpt from documentation:

> In the wire adapter’s configuration object, prefix a value with `$` to reference a property of the component instance. The `$` prefix tells the wire service to treat it as a property of the class and evaluate it as *`this.propertyName`*. The property is reactive. If the property’s value changes, new data is provisioned and the component rerenders.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. But there's another functionality missing. 

What is happening is when I click on a listview.. the table is not getting updated immediately... After I select another listview, the previous selected listviews' records are being shown. How do I overcome this?

Comment: @NikhilRayala If you have additional question, feel free to open a new question with the necessary details. Here at SFSE one question is specific to one problem and comments are used only for any further clarification on the original question.